# Clearing the NSUrlConnection cache on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, nsurlconnection

I've taken over development of an iPad app that's already been through several iterations. The app is designed to pick up a specific file for configuration settings from our website. However, only the most recent version of the app is designed to not cache this file, as the old version used NSUrlConnection. If one of the services the app depends on changes, users on older versions may have issues until their cache times out and they get a new configuration file.

I'd like to know what the best instruction to give users of older versions is (or at least the second best after "upgrade"). Is there a way to clear the NSUrlConnection cache manually? Will an uninstall/reinstall fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is the NSURLRequest (or it's mutable sibling) that controls the cache.

So have a look at reference of `NSURLRequest` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and choose most suitable `NSURLRequestCachePolicy`